# Add Sleep to a mySQL delete query

Tags: mysql

This is my delete query:

```
 delete from supplies where printerid = 49443
```

I want to create this in a loop with a sleep to allow other connections to process.
How can I do this?

Comment: Its not clear what you want..

Comment: because the delete locks the table and takes so long, it causes other connections to exceed the limit and the database to crash. I want to do the delete in chunks and allow a sleep (in a loop) to allow the other connections process time.

Comment: You should probably state what programming language you are using.

Comment: it is a simple mySQL query. I do plan to add it to a php script when it is working.

Comment: The info in comments must be added to the question. As it currently stands, the question cannot be anwered as it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

What you could use is a SLEEP().

```
DELETE...
SELECT SLEEP(1);
DELETE...
```

The duration is in seconds.

Refference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the delete it self is not so important and you want other important tasks to take priority if they come, you can use the `LOW_PRIORITY` flag, [Reference Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html#idm47110040633968)

```
 delete LOW_PRIORITY from supplies where printerid = 49443
```